# Docker in Pycharm: remote file X.py is mapped to the local path Y.py and can't be found

Tags: docker, pycharm, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to use a Docker container (anaconda)'s interpreter to run some code in Pycharm. My Run/Debug configs are set up properly and can run simple codes with the Docker interpreter.

However, there appears to be issues as soon as I import stuff. I'm not too familiar with how to set up mapping.

When I run my code, I'm getting an error

`"Remote file /opt/conda/envs/envname/lib/python3.6/codecs.py is mapped to the local path C:\Users\myname\PyCharm2018.1\system\remote_sources\...\codecs.py and can't be found"`

It appears that Pycharm is trying to map one of these library files to my Windows host machine?